# new Function() does not have access to arguments?

Tags: javascript

I try to use `new Function()` in a calculator and I find it does not have access to the arguments I'm passing to the function it's in. I'm using it like this:

```
function go(a, b, c) {
    return new Function('return a + b + c')();
}

go(4, '/', 2);
```

But it is not working because it says that a is undefined. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Why are you returning a function to return a function?

Comment: Why not `return function() { return a + b + c; };` - that'll work.

Comment: @Truth: I think it's a silly example to illustrate the issue :/

Comment: What is this even supposed to do?

Comment: Pointy is correct.  If you're going to write a function that returns a function ... then the *least* you can do is actually return a "function()" ;)

Comment: `I try to use new Function() in a` *`calculator`* o.O"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want:

```
function go(a, b, c) {
    return new Function('return ' + a + b + c + ';')();
}

go(4, '/', 2);
```

But this isn't the correct way to go. Make a distinct function for each action you're supporting.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this?

```
var add = function (a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c;
};
```

then invoke as such:

```
var sum = add(3, 4, 5); // sum is 12
```

Comment: That's not what he's trying to do. Note that one of the arguments given to go is an operator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Truth is correct in his assessment of what you are trying to achieve. However, I was curious as to why `a` was undefined.

As it turns out, the specification states that when `Function` is used as a constructor, the scope for the evaluated function body is the global environment:
[Section 15.3.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.2.1)

This is unlike `eval()` which uses the current scope.